# corr() with sparse matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, correlation, sparse-matrix

I wonder whether MATLAB has a toolbox to do common matrixial operation with sparse matrices.

Using a dense matrix, I can compute the correlogram matrix doing:

```
R = rand(10,100)
[r,p] = corr(R)
```

With sparse matrix I would love to do:

```
S = sprand(10,100,.2)
[r,p] = corr(S)
```

However, the following error is elicited:

```
Error using betainc
Inputs must be real, full, and double or single.

Error in tcdf (line 70)
    p(t) = betainc(xsq(t) ./ (v(t) + xsq(t)), 0.5, v(t)/2, 'upper') / 2;

Error in corr>pvalPearson (line 720)
    p = 2*tcdf(-abs(t),n-2);

Error in corr>corrPearson (line 321)
            pval(ltri) = pvalPearson(tail, coef(ltri), n);

Error in corr (line 204)
        [coef,pval] = corrFun(rows,tail,x);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I currently know of no function in MATLAB that can compute correlation on a sparse matrix.  You may have to implement that yourself.  However, this post on Cross Validated may give some insight: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120513/cross-correlation-for-very-sparse-binary-data

Comment: I do not know about any function doing this. In case matlab has not implemented this it is most likely that few matrices are sparse after using corr (examples: `corr(rand(10))`, `corr(toeplitz([2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]))`). If you want to implement this, then it is fine. However you may want to think about having a criteria where you assume correlation to be zero. Think of that a completely filled sparse matrix take about three times the size of a full matrix. Further, the example you show is not a case where sparse is recommended `s=sprand(10,10,.2); f=full(q); [r,p]=corr(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Cmon ppl, let's do some math! Let x be a random vector. An entry in the correlation matrix CORR(x_i, x_j) is given by:

```
CORR(x_i, x_j) = COV(x_i, x_j) / (SQRT(VAR(x_i)) *SQRT(VAR(x_j));
```

That is, to build our correlation matrix, we need the covariance matrix, which also gives us the individual variances. Formula for covariance: `COV(x) = E[x*x'] - E[x]E[x]'`. We can then approximate the the population moments `E[x*x']` with the sample moments (i.e. `X'*X/n` and `mean(X)`)

Hence the following Matlab code:

```
[n, k]  = size(X);
Exxprim = full(X'*X)/n; %I'm shocked if this isn't full so let's drop sparse now 
Ex   = full(mean(X))'; %same deal
COVX = (Exxprim - Ex*Ex');
STDEVX = sqrt(diag(COVX));
CORRX = COVX ./ (STDEVX * STDEVX');
```

This may help if X'*X and mean(X) can be done more efficiently because X is sparse.